# Why it's not selecting the answer I want?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

It's a simple Vue Quiz App, I don't know why it's happening this:

At the first question I choose the answer `a`, then click next, and in the next question I CAN'T choose `a` once again. So I choose `b` and at the third question the only answer I can choose is `c`.

Everything is working right except this thing, and I want to fix it.

Also how can I show random questions each time? So every time someone play the quiz, questions are shown always in a different order.

Why this is happening?

The Vue template

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="flex">
      <h2 class="title">Simple Quiz</h2>
      <div class="quiz">
        <div v-if="domandaCorrente < domande.length" class="question">
          <h2>{{ domande[domandaCorrente].domanda }}</h2>

          <label
            class="answer"
            :for="index"
            v-for="(risposta, index) in domande[domandaCorrente].risposte"
            :key="index"
            :class="{
              'hover border-grey': domandaScelta == '',
              'bg-red': domandaScelta == index,
              'bg-green':
                index == domande[domandaCorrente].rispostaCorretta &&
                domandaScelta != '',
            }"
          >
            <input
              type="radio"
              :name="index"
              :id="index"
              class="hidden"
              :value="index"
              @change="select($event)"
            />
            {{ risposta }}
          </label>
        </div>
        <div v-else>
          Results
          <div>
            <h2>
              Correct Answers: <span class="t-green">{{ correct }}</span>
            </h2>
            <h2>
              Wrong Answers: <span class="t-red">{{ wrong }}</span>
            </h2>
          </div>
          <button @click="reload()">Reload</button>
        </div>
        <div
          v-show="domandaScelta != '' && domandaCorrente < domande.length - 1"
          class="button"
        >
          <button @click="nextQuestion()">Next</button>
        </div>
        <div
          v-show="domandaScelta != '' && domandaCorrente == domande.length - 1"
          class="button"
        >
          <button @click="showResult()">Finish</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",

  data() {
    return {
      domandaCorrente: 0,
      correct: 0,
      wrong: 0,
      domandaScelta: "",
      
      domande: [
        {
          domanda: "Quante champions ha vinto il Milan?",
          risposte: { a: "2", b: "5", c: "7", d: "10" },
          rispostaCorretta: "c",
        },
        {
          domanda: "Quante champions ha vinto l'Inter?",
          risposte: { a: "1", b: "5", c: "7", d: "10" },
          rispostaCorretta: "a",
        },
        {
          domanda: "Quante champions ha vinto la Juve?",
          risposte: { a: "2", b: "5", c: "7", d: "10" },
          rispostaCorretta: "a",
        },
      ],
      
    };
  },

  methods: {
    select(e) {
      this.domandaScelta = e.target.value;
      console.log(this.domandaScelta)
      console.log(this.domandaCorrente)
      if(this.domandaScelta == this.domande[this.domandaCorrente].rispostaCorretta) {
        this.correct++
      } else {
        this.wrong++
      }
    },

    nextQuestion() {
      this.domandaScelta = ""
      this.domandaCorrente++
    },

    showResult() {
      this.domandaCorrente++
    },

    reload() {
      this.domandaCorrente = 0
      this.domandaScelta = ""
      this.wrong = 0
      this.correct = 0
    }
  },

  components: {},
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1- Add a `selected` variable to store selected input.

Set it as false when the user clicks on `nextQuestion`.

```
selected: false,
```

Set its value on `select` function:

```
this.selected = e.target.value
```

2- In your html code check the `checked` attribute with `selected`. Also correct `name` attribute to be equal for all of the inputs.

```
<input type="radio" :checked="index === selected" :name="`ans-${domandaCorrente}`" :id="`ans-${index}`" class="hidden" :value="index" @change="select($event)" />
```

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      domandaCorrente: 0,
      correct: 0,
      selected: false,
      wrong: 0,
      domandaScelta: "",
      domande: [{
          domanda: "Quante champions ha vinto il Milan?",
          risposte: {
            a: "2",
            b: "5",
            c: "7",
            d: "10"
          },
          rispostaCorretta: "c",
        },
        {
          domanda: "Quante champions ha vinto l'Inter?",
          risposte: {
            a: "1",
            b: "5",
            c: "7",
            d: "10"
          },
          rispostaCorretta: "a",
        },
        {
          domanda: "Quante champions ha vinto la Juve?",
          risposte: {
            a: "2",
            b: "5",
            c: "7",
            d: "10"
          },
          rispostaCorretta: "a",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    select(e) {
      this.selected = e.target.value
      this.domandaScelta = e.target.value;
      console.log(this.domandaScelta)
      console.log(this.domandaCorrente)
      if (this.domandaScelta == this.domande[this.domandaCorrente].rispostaCorretta) {
        this.correct++
      } else {
        this.wrong++
      }
    },
    nextQuestion() {
      this.selected = false;
      this.domandaScelta = ""
      this.domandaCorrente++
    },
    showResult() {
      this.domandaCorrente++
    },
    reload() {
      this.domandaCorrente = 0
      this.domandaScelta = ""
      this.wrong = 0
      this.correct = 0
    }
  },
  components: {},
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="flex">
    <h2 class="title">Simple Quiz</h2>
    <div class="quiz">
      <div v-if="domandaCorrente < domande.length" class="question">
        <h2>{{ domande[domandaCorrente].domanda }} </h2>

        <label class="answer" :for="index" v-for="(risposta, index) in domande[domandaCorrente].risposte" :key="index" :class="{
              'hover border-grey': domandaScelta == '',
              'bg-red': domandaScelta == index,
              'bg-green':
                index == domande[domandaCorrente].rispostaCorretta &&
                domandaScelta != '',
            }">
          <input type="radio" :checked="index === selected" :name="`ans-${domandaCorrente}`" :id="`ans-${index}`" class="hidden" :value="index" @change="select($event)" />
          {{ risposta }}
        </label>
      </div>
      <div v-else>
        Results
        <div>
          <h2>
            Correct Answers: <span class="t-green">{{ correct }}</span>
          </h2>
          <h2>
            Wrong Answers: <span class="t-red">{{ wrong }}</span>
          </h2>
        </div>
        <button @click="reload()">Reload</button>
      </div>
      <div v-show="domandaScelta != '' && domandaCorrente < domande.length - 1" class="button">
        <button @click="nextQuestion()">Next</button>
      </div>
      <div v-show="domandaScelta != '' && domandaCorrente == domande.length - 1" class="button">
        <button @click="showResult()">Finish</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```